# How to uninstall an exe generated using electron-builder

Tags: command-line, electron, exe, uninstallation, electron-builder

I am using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) to generate an `exe` (NSIS) file for my `electron` application. I am using the below commands in command prompt for installing and uninstalling.

```
myapplicaton.exe /install /noreboot /silent

myapplicaton.exe /uninstall /noreboot /silent
```

The install command is working, but the uninstall command does not work. There is no error shown as well. I did not find any leads in the web for uninstalling an exe generate using electron builder. Could you please let me know the correct way to uninstall the exe?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what kind of executable you actually mean: A standalone exe (obviously not), an NSIS installer, a WiX installer, ...? Have you tried anything besides these commands (uninstalling the app using Windows' settings, ...)? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, edited, thanks. target is nsis. Uninstall works from Add/Remove Programs, but that does not help. I need to write bat file to execute the commands for my use case.